# Travel to Romania with only Italy type D visa (work) but my residency permit has not been issued yet

Tags: international-travel, italy, romania, working-visas, residence-permits

I am in Italy with a D type work visa for two months and I applied for a residence permit card, and I am waiting for the time to deliver my documents.

Since my residence card has not yet been issued, can I travel to Romania only with a D-type work visa (one year)?

Answer (score 4):

> Since my residence card has not yet been issued, can I travel to Romania only with a D-type work visa (one year)?

Yes, a D-type visa (National visa) is a long-stay visa referred to in Article 18 of the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement.

Together with a multiple entry C-type visa (Schengen visa) or a residence permit, it allows you to transit (up to 5 days) or stay in Romania up to 90 days in any period of 180 days.

---

> **Conditions in which Foreign Citizens Can Transit Through Romania and Travel to Romania without a VISA**
> Third country nationals subject to visa requirements under Regulation (EC) No. 539/2001, may transit Romania within a period not exceeding 5 days **and have the right to stay in Romania for a period not exceeding 90 days in any period of 180 days without having obtained a Romanian visa in advance**, if:
>
> - they are holders of one of the following documents issued by the Member States of the European Union applying the Schengen acquis in full (Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Estonia, France, Finland, Germany, Greece, **Italy**, Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands , Poland, Portugal, Spain, Slovenia, Slovakia, Sweden, Hungary as well as Switzerland, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Norway):
>
>   - a uniform visa, as defined in Article 2 (3) of the Visa Code, valid for two entries or multiple entries;
>   - **a long-stay visa, referred to in Article 18 of the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement**;
>   - a residence permit as defined in Article 2 (15) of Regulation (EC) 562/2006;
> - has a national short stay visa, a long-stay national visa or a valid residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Cyprus and Croatia;

---

> [Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A42000A0922%2802%29)
> Section 2 **Long-stay visas**
>
> Article 18
>
> Visas for stays exceeding three months shall be national visas issued by one of the Contracting Parties in accordance with its national law. Such visas shall enable their holders to transit through the territories of the other Contracting Parties in order to reach the territory of the Contracting Party which issued the visa, unless they fail to fulfil the entry conditions referred to in Article 5(1)(a), (d) and (e) or they are on the national list of alerts of the Contracting Party through the territory of which they seek to transit.

---

**Sources**:

- [Conditions in which Foreign Citizens Can Transit Through Romania and Travel to Romania without a VISA - Main | Romanian Border Police](https://www.politiadefrontiera.ro/en/main/pg-conditions-in-which-foreign-citizens-can-transit-through-romania-and-travel-to-romania-without-a-visa-184.html)